# Format tick labels in a pandas.DataFrame.plot() without importing matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, string-formatting

Is it possible to format the tick labels in a `pandas.DataFrame.plot()` without importing the `matplotlib.ticker` library?

I've come to realise that `pandas` has many native functions I'm unaware of and I like to use them where possible — if only to simplify my code. And yes, `pandas` leans on `matplotlib` anyway, but I want to know to what extent I can style plots without directly invoking `matplotlib` functions.

For example, can I change the tick labels on this chart to percentages without `matplotlib.ticker.Percentformatter()`?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["value"], data=np.random.rand(5))
ax = df.plot.barh()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ticker.PercentFormatter(1))
plt.show()
```

[image: bar pot]

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom function as a string formatter with `set_major_formatter`.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["value"], data=np.random.rand(5))
ax = df.plot.barh()
func = lambda x, pos: f"{int(x*100)}%"
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(func)
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: ... but (note to OP), this is re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @BigBen, it's a straightforward answer but, yes, it's not less effort/code. I was wondering whether pandas has its own tick formatting functions/methods.

Comment: @Markus - note that [`ax.set_major_formatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter.html) is matplotlib, not pandas.

Comment: @BigBen, yes. I'd prefer a pandas-only solution, but it might not exist.

Comment: @Markus I am quite sure pandas does not provide any convenient function/plotting parameter for this. I believe this is as simple as it can get: `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.0%}')`